# Site id in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Where exactly is 'Site id' is stored in Alfresco .  I know we can create Site using Create Site option from Site menu . After creation  can i change / modify site id. I am not seeing that option ins 'Edit Site' menu. I can only change Display name.

Where is the 'Site id' stored in Alfresco ?

Regards

Comment: You can't change site-id from UI.

Comment: Thanks for the comment . Somone was configrued this already , but  i just want to know this id . Which configuration file its stored ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site-id is just the node name (cm:name) of the site root folder. Unfortunately it is not supported to change that name since this name is used in other node's metadata like a foreign key.